# How to write a regex in vim to match and replace arbitrary file location format

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex that takes a file path and keeps everything but the file, replacing it with /index.html.

For example:
replace
/home/hello.abc/file
to
/home/hello.abc/index.html

The file path can have arbitrary depth. The directory names and file names can contain any alphanumerical string and non-alphanumerical string except /

Comment: Why did you choose to use regex for this task?

Comment: what else can you do?

Comment: Split by last slash.

Comment: Like a find: `/?[^/]*$` and replace `/index.html` kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

This VIM regex will do the job:

```
:%s/\(^.*\/\).*/\1index.html
```

Because first group `\(^.*\/\)` match from beginning to last `/` character...